# How could Ivan Niven have come up with his proof that $\pi$ is irrational

Tags: calculus, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have a question about the proof listed [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788).

The proof is simple enough in that it begins with assuming that $\pi$ can be written as a fraction of two numbers, constructing a function on the basis of those two numbers and then finding two contradictory properties of this function.

**Now comes the question:** How could I have come up with this proof?

> As a second year math student I have to give a small talk about this proof. It would seem interesting if after proving it I could explain a bit about how Niven could have come up with this proof. The second part (where the function is shown to lie between 1 and 0) seems easy. For the first part he seemingly defines functions out of the sky and then those all neatly work together to show that the integral must have an integer as a value.

What I have found is that it is logical that $\sin(x)$ is involed, as otherwise no known property of $\pi$ would be used in the proof.

Comment: How could you have come up with this proof? Only by working hard and trying out many other methods, which didn't work, so that you would finally consider the problem in a right way. By the way, did you follow the posts here about Niven's proof? Start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588293/a-simple-proof-that-pi-is-irrational-by-ivan-niven). The read [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781652/understanding-proof-that-pi-is-irrational), and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21038/is-there-a-proof-that-pi-is-an-irrational-number) etc.

Comment: Related: ["a simple proof that $\pi$ is irrational by Ivan Niven"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2588293/409)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I followed, them, I found on wikipedia that before Niven's proof there were similar proofs, which I guess he could have read and have been inspired by to simplify?

Comment: Yes, indeed. There is a long list of proofs. It might be useful for your talk to have a look.

Comment: Perhaps something in one of the references I gave in my answer to [Irrationality of $\pi^2$ and $\pi^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2584927/13130) could be of use.