# Integral inequality in proof of irrationality of $\pi$

Tags: integration, number-theory, definite-integrals, proof-explanation

I'm trying to follow along with my textbook's proof of $\pi$ being irrational. One step in the proof (which my book takes for granted) confuses me. It states that, for each positive integer $n$,

$$0 < \int\limits_0^\pi \frac{(px-qx^2)^n}{n!}\hspace{3pt}\sin(x) \hspace{3pt}dx < \pi \cdot \frac{p^n}{n!}$$

where $\pi = p/q$ (this is a proof by contradiction).

I was able to manipulate the integral, using simple algebra, as follows:

$$\frac{q^n}{n!}\int\limits_0^\pi x^n(\pi-x)^n\hspace{3pt}\sin(x) \hspace{3pt}dx$$

Any hints as to how I might prove this inequality from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the interval $[0,\pi]$, we have
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
&0\le x(\pi-x)\le \frac{\pi^2}{4}\\[4pt]
&0\le \sin(x) \le 1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
hence
\begin{align*}
&
\frac{q^n}{n!}\int_0^\pi x^n(\pi-x)^n\sin(x)\,dx
\\[4pt]
\le\; &
\frac{q^n}{n!}\int_0^\pi \left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}\right)^n\,dx
\\[4pt]
=\; &
\left(\frac{q^n}{n!}\right)\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}\right)^n\left(\int_0^\pi 1\,dx\right)
\\[4pt]
=\; &
\left(\frac{q^n}{n!}\right)\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4}\right)^n(\pi)
\\[4pt]
=\; &
\left(\frac{(q\pi)^n}{n!}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^n(\pi)
\\[4pt]
=\; &
\left(\frac{p^n}{n!}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^n(\pi)
\\[4pt]
 < \; &
\pi{\,\cdot\,}\frac{p^n}{n!}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh, $\pi<4$! Interesting that it’s possible to shave $\pi^n$ off the estimate even though it’s not needed

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be $0 < \int\limits_0^\pi \frac{(px-qx^2)^n}{n!}\hspace{3pt}\sin(x) \hspace{3pt}dx <\frac{\pi^{n+1} p^n}{n!}$, (note the power of $\pi$) which follows because
$$(px-qx^2)^n = x^n(p-qx)^n \le \pi^n p^n$$
Here, $x\le \pi$ implies $x^n\le \pi^n$ and also $0\le x\le p/q$ implies $0\le qx\le p$ and therefore $p-qx \le p$.
My guess is backed up by this other question about this proof [a simple proof that $\pi$ is irrational by Ivan Niven](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588293/a-simple-proof-that-pi-is-irrational-by-ivan-niven) and the source paper [1].

See also [Is there a proof that $\pi$ is an irrational number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21038/is-there-a-proof-that-pi-is-an-irrational-number?noredirect=1&lq=1) for links to other proofs.

---

<sup>[1] *Niven, Ivan*, [**A simple proof that $\pi$ is irrational**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1947-08821-2), Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 53, 509 (1947). [ZBL0037.31404](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0037.31404).</sup>

Comment: But then it would be $\pi^{n+1}p^n,$ since the integral is from $0$ to $\pi.$

Comment: Indeed, I will edit @ThomasAndrews. Thanks for noticing

Comment: This makes sense; thanks for the thorough research. I'll look into this further to see if my book really did reproduce a mistake.

Comment: @Eragon20 can you say the name of your textbook? It might have an errata online

Comment: @CalvinKhor It's a private textbook from an old prof of mine; it's never been officially published. So definitely no online errata, alas.

Comment: @Eragon20 the other answer shows that the stronger estimate is indeed correct!

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for the comment section.*

Being interested by
$$I_n=\frac{1}{n!}\int\limits_0^\pi x^n(\pi-x)^n\hspace{3pt}\sin(x) \hspace{3pt}dx$$ I used the quadratic approximation given by @robjohn (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715358/where-am-i-violating-the-rules))
$$\sin(x) \sim \frac{31}{10\pi^2}(\pi-x)x+\frac{18}{5\pi^4}(\pi-x)^2x^2$$

This gives
$$I_n=\frac{1}{80} (n+1) \pi ^{2 n+1} \left(\frac{49 \sqrt{\pi } }{4^n\,\Gamma \left(n+\frac{5}{2}\right)}-\frac{288 \Gamma
   (n+4)}{\Gamma (2 n+6)}\right)$$ which is quite accurate (relative error smaller than $0.1$% if $n>4$).

I do not think it could be useful for your problem but the approximation of the integral was nice compared to the unpleasant rigorous solution
$$I_n=\left(\frac{\pi}{2 }\right)^{2 n+3} \Gamma (n+2) \,\,\,
   _2\tilde{F}_3\left(\frac{n+2}{2},\frac{n+3}{2};\frac{3}{2},n+\frac{3}{2},n+2;   -\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\right)$$ where appears the regularized generalized hypergeometric function.